# Should I use Trim function everytime when I insert data from webpage to database?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Should I use textbox.text.Trim() function every time when I insert any data from web page to database.

I just have a habit of using the trim function? Does it effect the performance any way? Should I use everytime or just when needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen many problems with spaces which had been added at the end to a text field by accident (for instance logins which mysteriously didn't work). So it's not a bad idea at all to trim() most textfield input as a standard practice.

I think the performance hit of a trim() is absolutely neglible, except maybe for sites with ultra high traffic.

Answer (score 1):

You should trim data as it comes into your application (from a submitted form), rather than just before you put it into the database. It's a validation step to get data into a controlled format, rather than an escaping step to store in a database safely. (*)

You should also be doing removal of control characters and anything else that will cause your application trouble at this point. For example, imagine the difficulty (and potential security problems) a username with a newline character or null byte in it could cause. A typical browser UI might not allow those characters to be typed, but that doesn't stop an attacker submitting them. Some form-reading libraries may take care of this for you, most won't.

Not everything needs trimming. For example big text fields like the one I'm typing in now might have a valid reason to have whitespace at the start and/or end. But it's worth doing for anything that has logic associated with it, most notably things like usernames.

*: there is one database issue with untrimmed spaces: many databases will silently trim trailing spaces, and unexpectedly match strings with any number of trailing spaces. Don't expect to get trailing spaces back from the database unless it's a BLOB column, and again, trim before doing anything with logic like matching usernames.

Answer (score 0):

Use trim and make sure you create a function to strip out any potential sql poisoning attacks.

php provides you

```
mysql_real_escape_string();
```

Comment: Seeing as how he's using ASP.NET, he should be using parameters. For that matter, so should PHP developers.

Comment: yup i m using asp.net & dataset for all my CURD. what should i do prevent sql injection ?